# Refencing a common definitions for nested objects

Tags: json, jsonschema

Let me try to explain what I am trying to do. My JSON looks something like this

**My.json:**

```
{
    "overrides": {
        "key1": {
            "DRM": {
                "queue": "q1",
                "resource": "r1m<0.5"
            }
        },
        "key2": {
            "DRM": {
                "queue": "q2",
                "resource": "r1m<0.4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Schema:**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "test-schema.json",
    "definitions": {
        "DRM": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "queue": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "resource": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "key-objs": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "DRM": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/DRM"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "overrides": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key1": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/key-objs"
                },
                "key2": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/key-objs"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is every time I define a new `key` inside `overrides` (e.g: **key3, key4**), I need to update my schema, make it reference the `key-objs`.

I know that the `overrides` object can be turned into a list and all the items in the list could define `key-objs`. However I don't want to change `overrides` into a list.

Is there a way for me to say all the objects inside `overrides` should reference `key-objs` without exclusively specifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the schema of un-specified keys using `"additionalProperties": {schemaComesHere}`

So instead of defining properties one by one, you can do

```
  "overrides": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/key-objs"
      }
  }
```